# Implementar Fluxo de Aprovação de Texto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde o usuário poderá publicar textos, porém antes de ser postado no site precisa ser aprovado, algo similar aos convites de amizade das redes sociais onde é necessário esperar a aprovação de outra pessoa ou sistema antes de concretizar a ação.

Na minha tabela `textos` do banco tem os seguintes campos:

- idusuari(quem escreveu o texto),
- idtexto,
- texto e
- idadmin(que é quem ira aprovar o texto ou não).

A maior dúvida é como armazenar esse dado pois como o `id` do admin é obrigatório e o texto pode demorar alguns dias para ser aprovado ou não, não ha como fazer o "insert" direto no banco.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a implementá-lo?

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta ao certo, mas se sua regra de negocio diz que para ser publicado precisa ser APROVADO (opa, isso vira atributo rs) então, ao menos, você já precisa de um campo na sua tabela chamado status e/ou aprovado(sim/nao) para validar este estado em qualquer parte que seja do seu sistema. E como você diz, se você precisa de um admin para aprovar, ele NÃO deve ser requerido (idadmin) no momento da inserção.

Answer (score 3):

Estou supondo que seu sistema usa Entity Framework.

Vou deduzir seu *Model* de textos:

```
public class Texto 
{
    [Key]
    public int TextoId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public int AdminId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required]
    public String Texto { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Admin { get; set; }
}
```

Se o texto precisa de aprovação, é impossível não haver persistência no processo (ou, como você diz, não haver inserção). O que se pode fazer é enriquecer seu *Model* para que esse texto não apareça de cara quando inserido. Ou seja:

```
public class Texto 
{
    [Key]
    public int TextoId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public int AdminId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required]
    public String Texto { get; set; }

    public Boolean Aprovado { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAprovacao { get; set; } 

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Admin { get; set; }
}
```

Booleanos no Entity Framework são default `false`, então inserindo um novo texto, ele é lançado como `Aprovado = false;`.

Feito isso, basta que você escreva uma `Action` para o administrador aprovar o texto. Algo assim:

```
public ActionResult Aprovar(int id)
{
    var texto = contexto.Textos.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TextoId == id);

    if (UsuarioEhAdministrador) // Coloque aqui seu critério para verificar se usuário é Administrador
    {
        texto.Aprovado = true;
        texto.DataAprovacao = DateTime.Now;

        contexto.Entry(texto).State = EntityState.Modified;
        contexto.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Textos");
    }
}
```

E para não exibir textos não aprovados, use:

```
var textos = contexto.Textos.Where(t => T.Aprovado).ToList();
```

Comment: entendi. Mas como ficaria a action de inserção do texto. Por que mesmo que ela seja aprovada depois, o id d admin deve entrar na hora da inserção certo? Ou eu posso deixar o id do admin como nulo para inserir depois com a aprovação?

Comment: @GuilhermeVinicius O ideal é que o Id do aprovador seja colocado na aprovação, assim qualquer admin será apto a aprovar. A lógica também fica mais simples. A inserção, portanto, fica trivial, apenas com o texto e o id do autor.